# NameError: uninitialized constant User::BooksAndUser in has_many :through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I seem to have wired my associations wrong in my rails 4 application. This is basically my setup (though a little bit contrived)

**Models:**

**book.rb**

```
class Book < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :books_and_users
  has_many :users, through: :books_and_users
  validates :user_id, presence: true
end
```

**user.rb**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  has_many :books_and_users
  has_many :books, through: :books_and_users
  validates :name, presence: true
end
```

**book_and_user.rb**

```
class BooksAndUser < ActiveRecord::Base
  self.table_name = "books_and_users"
  belongs_to :book
  belongs_to :user
  validates :user, presence: true
  validates :book, presence: true
end
```

**Schema**

```
create_table "books", force: true do |t|
  t.string   "name"
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
  t.integer  "user_id"
end

add_index "books", ["user_id"], name: "index_books_on_user_id"

create_table "books_and_users", force: true do |t|
  t.integer "user_id"
  t.integer "book_id"
end

add_index "books_and_users", ["book_id"], name: "index_books_and_users_on_book_id"
add_index "books_and_users", ["user_id"], name: "index_books_and_users_on_user_id"

create_table "users", force: true do |t|
  t.string   "email",                  default: "", null: false
  t.datetime "created_at"
  t.datetime "updated_at"
  t.string   "name"
end
```

When I want to check the models are setup correctly in rails console I do the following:

```
u = User.first
u.books => NameError: uninitialized constant User::BooksAndUser
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Try changing the `books_and_users` association in `User` and `Book` to specify the class name like so: `has_many :books_and_users, class_name: "BooksAndUser"` And I think your `table_name` specification in `BooksAndUser` might be necessary. Try removing that line. P.S. You forgot to share the code of your `Book` model - you shared the `BookAndUser` model twice in your post.

Comment: @Humza I did all that but still get the same error. :-(

Comment: Does the error tell you which line the error is on?

Comment: `from /Library/Ruby/Gems/2.0.0/gems/activerecord-4.0.8/lib/active_record/inheritance.rb:129:in compute_type` is the first line, but it does not say anything about my code. Seems to be most builtin callbacks

Answer (score 0):

rename `book_and_user.rb` to `books_and_user.rb`